# Web scraping code with beautifulsoup library didn't get the expected result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
}

r = requests.get("http://pyclass.com/real-estate/rock-springs-wy/LCWYROCKSPRINGS/", headers=headers)
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "propertyRow"})

for item in all:
    print(item.find("h4", {"class": "propPrice"}).text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", ""))
    print(item.find_all("span", {"class": "propAddressCollapse"})[0].text)
    print(item.find_all("span", {"class": "propAddressCollapse"})[1].text)
    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class": "infoBed"}).find("b").text)
    except:
        print(None)

    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class": "infoValueFullBath"}).text)
    except:
        print(None)

    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class": "infoSqFt"}).text)
    except:
        print(None)

    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class": "infoValueHalfBath"}).text)
    except:
        print(None)

    for column_group in item.find_all("div", {"class":"columnGroup"}):
        print(type(column_group))
        for feature_group, feature_name in zip(column_group.find_all("span", {"class":"feature_Group"}),column_group.find_all("span", {"class":"feature_Name"})):
            if "Lot Size" in feature_group.text:
                print(feature_name.text)
    print(" ")
```

Comment: How many times do you think it should loop, and why?

Comment: Also, in your own words, what do you think is the purpose of doing `except: print(None)`? How do you intend to diagnose the problem if you ignore the exception message?

Comment: This coe didn't print the LAST for loop's print() statement. what do i do in that case?

Comment: your class is not correct in last for loop class name should be `featureGroup` and `featureName`

Comment: Yes, i got that last day. Thanks BTW